# Convert emoticons like :-) and :-P to graphics on display

Tags: wordpress

I am getting comments from `wp_comments` table but when display it on browser it does not show **emoticons** instead showing `:)` and `:D` though comment have some emoticons. I read [Using Smilies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies) and now I want to create custom function which replace `:)` with appropriate icon and so on.

But I have no idea how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page describes the use of Emoticons/Smileys as graphics:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies

- Go to your Admin Panel
- Select Settings -> Writing
- Check the box for "Convert emoticons like :-) and :-P to graphics on display"

If you're looking for the wp-script that converts the emoticons look here:

```
httpdocs/wp-includes/formatting.php
```

***~line: 1715***

```
/**
 * Convert one smiley code to the icon graphic file equivalent.
 *
 * Looks up one smiley code in the $wpsmiliestrans global array and returns an
 * <img> string for that smiley.
 *
 * @global array $wpsmiliestrans
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @param string $smiley Smiley code to convert to image.
 * @return string Image string for smiley.
 */
function translate_smiley($smiley) {
```

...

```
/**
 * Convert text equivalent of smilies to images.
 *
 * Will only convert smilies if the option 'use_smilies' is true and the global
 * used in the function isn't empty.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @uses $wp_smiliessearch
 *
 * @param string $text Content to convert smilies from text.
 * @return string Converted content with text smilies replaced with images.
 */
function convert_smilies($text) {
```

Comment: check "How Can I Have Different Smiley Images Appear?" Isn't that what you looking for?

Comment: buddy i know it well but i think u did not read my text. I am getting comments from wp_comments table & want to show on browser with emoticons

Comment: Sorry, i still don't get it - the wp_comments converts the emoticons like :) and :D if the box is checked. At least in my configuration...

Comment: Thanks buddy it is not the exact function but on below function convert_smilies($text) {} is exactly what i was searching

Comment: @PHPFerrari: what Sven is saying is that Wordpress does this all for you. It works automatically for me `:)`.